# Why this program is crashing?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int *p = (int *)malloc(1*4);
    for(;;)
    {
        scanf("%d", p+i);
        if(*(p+i) == 42)
        {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        printf("%dn", j);
    }
}
```

Since I knew that I have  created only one block of 4 bytes but since we get the base address stored in `p` then I could have explored the address under the loop as much as I want i.e. I would store the values in contiguous memory location until 42 is encountered, The problem is that the program is working fine for 5 inputs but the program is getting crashed if the inputs are exceeding more than five.

I found the solution for this to be Undefined behaviour as defiened by Alex Lop But further I want to know why this works????

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    int *p=(int *)malloc(1*4);
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",p+i);
    }
}
```

Here on printing the address outside the allocated bunch of memory it does not crashes, it finally prints the address which I have not allocated.

Comment: "But further I want to know why this works" - it is undefined, may work and may not, may cook you sandwich (unlikely) and may destroy the universe (even more unlikely).

Answer (score 3):

What yo actually do is called "undefined behavior".

You allocate 4 bytes and then store into that buffer integers. It works fine for the first integer (or maybe two if `sizeof(int)==2` on your machine) but for the next integer the behavior becomes undefined. It may segfault immediately and it may take more similar stores until you crash. The number of inputs '5' here doesn't mean anything, it may behave differently on different machines and with different compilation flags.

According to what I see (or assume from the code), you want to accept inputs until you get "42". So actually you don't have to store the input values. Here is **your** code without the useless stuff:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int in;

    for(;;)
    {
        scanf("%d",&in);
        printf("%d\n", in); // adding this line because it was explained to
                            // me that the input values should be printed and 
                            //it is something I couldn't understand from the original code.
        if(in == 42)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Noy only I want to stop on encountring 42  but I want to print them also, Never the less It would be great if you could explain me the mechanism working behind this error

Comment: @GauravJoshi You've told the program you want to allocate 4 bytes in memory. But you've accessed many bytes beyond those that were allocated for you. That in itself is an error. It's called undefined behaviour because your code may read values without giving you any error, or may simply crash. And that's what you're seeing. Alex's solution doesn't involve any news and is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @GauravJoshi I edited my answer. Now it prints the input value but still without storing them all. It just prints them one by one. Regarding your error I'll explain in a few minutes here in the comments.

Comment: @AlexLop. I want to enter them one by one and then finally prints them all which u could see from my first infinite loop , I want the use to first enter all the inputs and then if it ecounters 42 then it should prints all which precedds it

Comment: But  I am not looking for the program to be done , What I want  through this example is that what concept I am lacking

Comment: @GauravJoshi When you allocate X bytes (using `malloc` or similar mechanisms) the OS guarantees you to reserve these X bytes for you and the pointer to the beginning of this X bytes is returned to you. Nobody knows what lays beyond these X bytes in the memory. Maybe it is a junk and maybe it is other sensitive data which you may corrupt if you write beyond the X bytes range. And maybe that this memory range was not allocated/mapped at all and then you will get segfault even on read access.

Comment: @aslg It  means the C language does not allows us to chhose a particular address and then contigously increament that address untill I want to store the values in the contigously incrementing address by a diiference of   sizeof(int)

Comment: @GauravJoshi So in your case, when you don't know the input length, you may either do what you did BUT for each new input you will have to allocate the new buffer with size of the previous one + `sizeof(int)`, copy the old values, store the new one. Or you may learn something new and read about "linked list".

Comment: @AlexLop. I have edited my post  . Have a look on it

Comment: @GauravJoshi Because you only print the **address**, you don't access the content.

Comment: @GauravJoshi since you marked my answer as the "solution" for your problem you better write a new questions instead of editing this one since few people will look at already answered question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to realloc your dynamic array p in order to store all values (i values). In your code, you've space for only one integer (1*4).

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int i=0,j=0;
    int *p=(int *)malloc(1*sizeof(int)); //You can use sizeof(int) instead of 4
    for(;;) {
        p = realloc(p, (i+1)*sizeof(int)); //p can now store i integers
        scanf("%d",p+i);
        if(*(p+i)==42) { 
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    for(j=0;j<i;j++) {
        printf("%d\n",j);
    }
}
```

Comment: But through this example I want to know Why it is working fine if the inputs are less than 6

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where to begin. Where did you even get the idea of doing this to yourself?

First, you have to specify that you want to allocate in blocks with `sizeof(int)`. Because the actual value might change for different implementations (even if it usually is 4).

Your program is not working fine. You can't explore the address as much as you want because you're running into undefined behaviour. You have allocated 4 bytes but are accessing memory beyond what you've allocated. Doesn't matter how many iterations it takes to crash (could've been 1 or 2, or 100), it's just wrong.

Comment: if it's wrong then why it is working fine for (lets say) 3 inputs which should have occupied 3*4 =12 bytes

Comment: @GauravJoshi just how many times have you to be told that the behaviour of your process is undefined?  It 'works' for, (lets say) ,3 inputs because that that behaviour is in the set of [undefined].